# Error for no installation of react-native

Tags: react-native

Peace be upon you!
I tried to run my react-native project which previously did work correctly. However, after sometime I came back and tried, as a result, I got this error which tells me that ""react-native-web" is added as a dependency in your project's package.json but it doesn't seem to be installed. Please run "yarn" or "npm install" to fix this issue."
Any solutions for this?

Comment: Kindly share he error as well

Comment: Have you ran npm install?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**ERROR:**

"react-native" is added as a dependency in your project's package.json but it doesn't seem to be installed. Please run "yarn" or "npm install" to fix this issue.

[React-native Expo package.json error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWNpW.png)

**SOLUTION:**

**READ MORE:** https://docs.expo.io/

Unable to start the project.

**Follow** these steps to solve the problem and start the project:

1. **Delete** the node_modules folder.
2. Run "**yarn install**" or "**npm install**".
3. Run "**expo start**" or "**npm start**".

[React-native Expo package.json error solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHELM.png)

I hope this should solve your problem!